# Table format uncorrect

Tags: tables, siunitx, sidewaystable

Why with table-format the decimals are still longer than 2?

[image]

```
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering
\footnotesize
\caption{P-value delle variabili nella regressione suddivisa per anno}
\label{tab:pvalue}
\begin{tabular}{l
        S[round-precision=2]
        S[round-precision=2]
        S[round-precision=2]
        S[round-precision=2]
        S[round-precision=2]
        S[round-precision=2]
        S[round-precision=2]
        S[round-precision=2]
        S[round-precision=2]
        S[round-precision=2]
    }
    \toprule
    p-value & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2014h1} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l} 
    {2014h2} 
    &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2015h1} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l} 
    {2015h2} 
    &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2016h1} &  \\
   \toprule
    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Estimate} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{pValue} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Estimate} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{pValue} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Estimate} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{pValue} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{Estimate} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{pValue} & 
   \multicolumn{1}{l}{Estimate} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{pValue} \\
   (int.) & 3.5506 & 0     & 3.4812 & 0     & 3.4562 & 0     & 3.5235 & 0     
    & 3.6523 & 0 \\
   CurrentInterestRateIndex & 0.69827 & 0     &       &       &       &       
   &       &       &       &  \\
   ObligorLegalFormBusinessTy &       &       &       &       &       &       
   &       &       &       &  \\
   BorrowerBaselIIISegment &       &       &       &       &       &       &       
   &       &       &  \\
   Seniority & 1.4895 & 0.0003 & 1.4935 & 0     & 0.59807 & 0.29  & 1.3258 & 
   0     & 0.94451 & 0 \\
   InterestRateType &       &       &       &       &       &       &       
   &       &       &  \\
  code\_nace & 1.0486 & 0     & 0.95254 & 0.00342 & 0.79864 & 0.056 & 
  0.92741 
  & 0.06  & 0.94746 & 0.003 \\
 NumberofCollateralItemsSecur &       &       &       &       &       &       
 &        &       &       &  \\
WeightedAverageLife & 1.007 & 0     & 0.95374 & 0     & 1.1689 & 0     & 
0.91267 & 0     & 0.79859 & 0 \\
maturity &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
payment\_ratio & 2.4564 & 0     & 2.2966 & 0     & 1.4822 & 0     & 2.3007 & 0     & 2.2537 & 0 \\
loanToValue &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
geographic\_area & 1.6753 & 0     & 1.4052 & 0.01893 & 1.432 & 0     &       &       & 0.90343 & 0.0217 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{sidewaystable}
```

Comment: You probably want to turn on rounding with `round-mode=places`

Comment: Where should I insert it? sorry I'm not so expert, even without a whole thesis done in latex

Comment: Just write `S[round-mode=places,round-precision=2]` instead of `S[round-precision=2]`

Answer (score 5):

In addition to adding the option `round-mode=places`, you should try to make the table more easily parsable for your readers. For instance, you may want to reorganize the header material to provide more visual grouping.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating,caption,booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\sisetup{round-mode=places,round-precision=2}
\centering
\footnotesize
\caption{P-value delle variabili nella regressione suddivisa per anno}
\label{tab:pvalue}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{10}{S} @{}}
\toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2014h1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2014h2} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2015h1} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2015h2} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{2016h1} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} 
\cmidrule(lr){8-9} \cmidrule(l){10-11} 
    & {Estimate} & {pValue} & {Estimate} & {pValue} & {Estimate} & {pValue} & 
      {Estimate} & {pValue} & {Estimate} & {pValue} \\
\midrule
   (int.) & 3.5506 & 0 & 3.4812 & 0 & 3.4562 & 0 & 3.5235 & 0 & 3.6523 & 0 \\
   CurrentInterestRateIndex & 0.69827 & 0 & & & & & & & &  \\
   ObligorLegalFormBusinessTy & & & & & & & & & &  \\
   BorrowerBaselIIISegment & & & & & & & & & &  \\
   Seniority & 1.4895 & 0.0003 & 1.4935 & 0 & 0.59807 & 0.29 & 1.3258 & 0 & 0.94451 & 0 \\
   InterestRateType & & & & & & & & & &  \\
   code\_nace & 1.0486 & 0 & 0.95254 & 0.00342 & 0.79864 & 0.056 & 0.92741 & 0.06  & 0.94746 & 0.003 \\
   NumberofCollateralItemsSecur & & & & & & & & & &  \\
   WeightedAverageLife & 1.007 & 0 & 0.95374 & 0 & 1.1689 & 0 & 0.91267 & 0 & 0.79859 & 0 \\
   maturity & & & & & & & & & &  \\
   payment\_ratio & 2.4564 & 0 & 2.2966 & 0 & 1.4822 & 0 & 2.3007 & 0 & 2.2537 & 0 \\
   loanToValue & & & & & & & & & &  \\
   geographic\_area & 1.6753 & 0 & 1.4052 & 0.01893 & 1.432 & 0 & & & 0.90343 & 0.0217 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to turn on rounding with (probably) `round-mode=places` (there is also `round-mode=figures`)

```
\begin{tabular}{l
        S[round-precision=2,round-mode=places]
        S[round-precision=2,round-mode=places]
        S[round-precision=2,round-mode=places]
        S[round-precision=2,round-mode=places]
        S[round-precision=2,round-mode=places]
        S[round-precision=2,round-mode=places]
        S[round-precision=2,round-mode=places]
        S[round-precision=2,round-mode=places]
        S[round-precision=2,round-mode=places]
        S[round-precision=2,round-mode=places]
    }
```

If all columns are set with the same settings you can simplify your definition to

```
\begin{tabular}{l*{10}{S[round-precision=2,round-mode=places]}}
```